# CKAN - Merge Organizations

Tags: ckan

I'm working with ckanext-harvest and coming up against issues where datasets are owned by seperate organisations that are a few characters off being the same.

Is there a way to merge organisations? Or unless some funky python library is being used to connect to PostgreSQL point me at the SQL and I can fix it.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Did you check remote_orgs configuration option for harvester?

From the harvester docs:
By default, remote organizations are ignored. Setting this property enables the harvester to import remote organizations. There are two alternatives. Setting it to 'only_local' will just import organizations which id is already present in the local CKAN. Setting it to 'create' will make an attempt to create the organizations by copying the details from the remote CKAN.
For more info check [harvester docs](http://%20https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-harvest#the-ckan-harvester).